# Inverter power for my power tools

Tags: electrical

So I was looking into (and might, might not) installing a small solar panel setup. I was reading on DC to AC converters and there is modified and pure sine wave. I was reading how modified can over heat, be less efficient so on and so forth. That scares me and so I looked at pure sine, since it would not be a problem. But dang those are pricey! A pure is $200 where a modified could be as much as $50. And unless I actually got one for 'cheap' I will not do this...

The tools I would use this on would be my band saw, router, and any other tool that basically uses less than 5 Amps.

So, is it going to be a bad thing to use a modified converter? Will I wear down my tool much sooner? Will overheating be a problem? Anything on this would help.

Note: This came directly from the woodworking group. So if I left something out that is needed then please let me know and I will gladly update

Added: SO I was thinking, what could I make for a circuit to take the Sine wave from a modified to "clean it up" into a more, pure wave form. Or something fairly cheap that I could bye, I wanted a 2000 watt but... may not happen, not rich! Anything with that would help!

Comment: Trying to clean up a modified sine wave would cost as much as purchasing the pure sine inverter. The modified sine wave is basically square wave in smaller steps depending on the model and these are full of harmonics that create the over heating in the motors. I have run cord connected motors on modified sine but limit the duty cycle to prevent over heating. I found that 10-15 minutes was as long as I was willing to run my tools without at least 15 minutes to cool down, this worked well until I was able to bring my generator out to do a large remodel on an off grid cabin.

Comment: @EdBeal Okay, that is good to know. Understand I need to have a larger converter for  bigger tools, but does it make any different if it was a 15 amp (like my planer/table saw) over a 2.5 amp tool (band saw/drill press). Thank you for the quick response.

Comment: The motors in band saws and table saws will over heat if run for extended times on a modified sine inverter. The tools I was mentioning above were table saw, chop saw, skill saw. My table saw got quite hot to the point I pulled the stator and revarnished the windings, With the skill and chop saws I only run these for a couple minutes at a time but the skill saw did get warm. If you don't push the tools for an extended time they will work but watch out with my table saw it was warm at 10 minutes and two hot to touch at under 20 minutes of ripping 1/2" plywood.

Comment: Why does the modified sine wave cause overheating? I understand about the harmonics, but why does that create heat?